# Separate intersection between an object and a generic object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

### Problem

I have a value that is an [intersection](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) between a generic `object` `A` and `{ _id: string }`.

I wanted to split this intersection again, and return the `_id` separatly from the rest (in a tuple).

So I tried the following (which logically should work):

```js
function splitDataAndId<A extends object>(a: A & { _id: string }): [string, A] {
  const { _id, ...data } = a;
  return [_id, data]; // type error
}
```

It produces the following type error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Pick<A & { _id: string; }, Exclude<keyof A, "_id">>' is not assignable to 
type 'A'. 'Pick<A & { _id: string; }, Exclude<keyof A, "_id">>' is assignable to the constraint of 
type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.
```

### Question

Can this problem be solved by either improving the types, or by changing the implementation?

Comment: I can do `return [_id, data as A];`, but is that not just tricking the compiler?

Comment: Have you tried A | ... instead of A & .... ?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe that has completely different semantics, though.

Comment: The word "union" is being used here but the example code has [intersections](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), not [unions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).  Can we change either the wording or the code?

Comment: @jcalz You are of course completely correct. I've updated the text.

Answer (score 2):

It can be fixed at the type level only. Consider:

```
function splitDataAndId<A extends { _id: string }>(a: A): [string, Omit<A, '_id'>] {
  const { _id, ...data } = a;
  return [_id, data]; // is ok
}
```

The issue which you had is related to lack of relation between newly computed type `A & { _id: string }` and `A` itself. You can understand that as you would introduce additional variable at the type level. If we transform type `A` directly from beginning then everything here match with the implementation. The constraint about having `_id` key is placed into generic type and not in argument type.

Consider that I am using `A` and doing transformation on `A` only by `Omit<A, '_id'>` which is really type level equivalent of your value level transformation (both are removing `_id` from the original structure)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwA4BsZQCIEMq4CCYAJgJIkA8hiApgB5S2nKIDeiA+jCQFwpQATjDABzRAF8AfAApc-QgEp+AbWRCRogDSIA8gFss1HQHJuJE1IC67AFCJEEBOvZceOgHReS+XJMQAvIi4ANz2iIK0UCCCSCrmOj4EViGIAPRpiDCscADWthJAA)